# Copy files with certain extension from many nested sub-directories to a single directory and append to each copied file the name of the directory

Tags: grep, scripting, find, regular-expression, rsync

I have a parent directory with thousands of directories within sub-directories and so on. In `some` of the sub-directories I have few image files.

I want to copy (`rsync` is preferred) all of the `bmp` and `jpg` files from the sub-directories to a single new directory without any sub-directories. But at the same time I want to append the name of the LAST directory where the file comes from to the copied file.

```
├── example1
│   ├── fdfd
│   │   ├── db_files
│   │   │   ├── asdasd.zip
│   │   │   ├── dfdfsta.zip
│   │   │   ├── csf_4545.zip
│   │   │   ├── 45455.zip
│   │   │   ├── 4544.zip
│   │   │   ├── 45545.zip
│   │   │   ├── gfdfgd.zip
│   │   │   ├── retert.zip
│   │   │   ├── vcxvxc.zip
│   │   │   ├── vcxcvcx.zip
│   │   │   ├── asdr3.zip
│   │   │   ├── tetst.zip
│   │   │   ├── testeh.bmp
│   │   │   └── testst43.zip
│   │   ├── TEST_FILE.bmp
│   │   └── hfexport.csv
│   └── testFOLDER2018-05
│       ├── Databasef.txt
│       ├── Folder_Backup_2014-01-05.7z
│       ├── full_Export.pdf
│       ├── f-to-7000.csv
│       ├── f-to-505.csv
│       ├── f-to-600.csv
│       ├── f-to-960.bmp
│       ├── g-to-1000.jpg
│       └── 7000.csv
├── example3
│   ├── img_copy
│   │   ├── automation
│   │   │   ├── f.sh
│   │   │   ├── fff.sh
│   │   │   └── test.bat
│   │   ├── all.bmp
│   │   ├── h23.txt
│   │   ├── old2_copy.jpg
```

In the example above, the copied files will be as follows:

```
db_files_testeh.bmp
fdfd_TEST_FILE.bmp
testFOLDER2018-05_f-to-960.bmp
testFOLDER2018-05_g-to-1000.jpg
img_copy_all.bmp
img_copy_old2_copy.jpg
```

How can I achieve this?

I use the following commands to copy only `bmp` and `jpg` files to a new directory.

```
find -regex '.*\.\(bmp\|jpg\)' | tee /home/tmp/matches.txt
while read -r LINE; do rsync -vh --append-verify --chmod=ugo=rwX --progress --stats "$LINE" /mnt/storage3/backups/NEW_DIR/ONLY_IMAGES; done < /home/tmp/matches.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f '(' -name '*.bmp' -o -name '*.jpg' ')' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        newname="${pathname%/*}_${pathname##*/}"  # a/b/c/d.bmp --> a/b/c_d.bmp
        newname="target/${newname##*/}"           # a/b/c_d.bmp --> target/c_d.bmp

        printf "Would move %s to %s\n" "$pathname" "$newname"
        # mv -i "$pathname" "$newname"
    done' sh {} +
```

This finds all regular files whose filenames end with either `.jpg` or `.bmp`.  For batches of these files, a short shell script is executed.

The shell script extracts the directory pathname of each file, along with its filename and concatenates the two with an underscore in-between.  This forms the new name.  The new name is then trimmed of it's initial directories, leaving only the filename, and a target directory path is appended to this.

The final `mv` is commented out for safety.  Run this once with it commented out to see that it does the correct thing.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: Great answer. It works exactly as I wanted. I believe replace the `mv` section with `rsync "$pathname" "$newname"` should not pose any problems, correct?

Comment: At least when I put `rsync --dry-run "$pathname" "$newname"` in place of `mv`, I do not recognize any suspicious behavior.

Comment: @zirodec That should be okay to do, yes. I forgot that you wanted to use `rsync`.

Comment: @zirodec But keep in mind that you can have name clashes if two files have the same name but reside in different directories, and those parent directories too can have same names if there parents' name differ.